# How can I add values from existing object to new object dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have an empty new object and I want to populate values from an existing object to new object because I want to use an object with only limited properties from the existing object (e.g. I only want the four properties instead of eight).

Here's how I am doing the mapping so far:

```
  const newObject: any = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < this.PRODUCT_DATA.length; i++) {

       newObject._productSkuKey = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._productSkuKey;
       newObject._storeKey = this.itemPriceForm.get('location').value;
       newObject._price = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._price;
       newObject._status = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._isActive;
       this.updatedProducts.push(newObject);
    }
```

So far, it looks to be storing the values from the existing object to newObject. However, it is only saving the last object values and not the different values from the object. How can I fix this to save all values (not just the last values for every object in the array)?

Comment: Put `const newObjects = ` into the loop.

Comment: @JonasW. I'm an idiot, thanks Jonas! FML

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a copy of that before pushing in array

```
const newObject: any = {};
for (let i = 0; i < this.PRODUCT_DATA.length; i++) {

   newObject._productSkuKey = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._productSkuKey;
   newObject._storeKey = this.itemPriceForm.get('location').value;
   newObject._price = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._price;
   newObject._status = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._isActive;
   this.updatedProducts.push(Object.assign({}, newObject));
   // Or
   // this.updatedProducts.push({ ...newObjec });
}
```

Or Simply create object inside loop. I love to use `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.map`

```
this.updatedProducts = this.PRODUCT_DATA.map(({_productSkuKey, _price, _isActive})=> ({
        _productSkuKey,
        _storeKey: this.itemPriceForm.get('location').value,
        _price,
        _status: _isActive
   });
```

Comment: You are most kind, but I'm just a novice ;)

Comment: @AluanHaddad if you are novice then it means I am little kid :D

Answer (score 0):

Avoid declaring newObject as 'const'. This is an updated code that works for me.

```
//avoid using a const, as you cannot override it
  let newObject: any = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < this.PRODUCT_DATA.length; i++) {

   newObject._productSkuKey = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._productSkuKey;
   newObject._storeKey = this.itemPriceForm.get('location').value;
   newObject._price = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._price;
   newObject._status = this.PRODUCT_DATA[i]._isActive;
   this.updatedProducts.push(newObject);
   //after pushing the object, empty all the current contents
   newObject={};
}
```